# Configuring attributes for SmartTarget filters for multiple publications

Tags: smarttarget

I have a schema field which I want to use as a possible filter value on SmartTarget content selection. When I check the Fredhopper Business Manager System->Navigation section, I see the field is listed once for each publication content is published in with a slightly different identifier (eg *metadata_tcm_79_10117_8_activity* - the publication id bit varies).

If I want to create local Promotions that can use this field as a filter, do I need to make all instances of the field a live attribute the list? If not, which entry should I choose from the list to make live (the parent publication?). If so, is there any way to avoid this overhead and associated maintenance issues when, for example bringing new sites online.

Answer (score 2):

To quote [from the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-89150A23-9762-4A12-A9C7-437ED47C2166):

> Content selection, including filtering, occurs on the selected Publication level, and *not* at Child Publication level.

As such, the attribute that needs to be live is the one that belongs to the Publication that you choose within the Promotion editing screen. So if you want people to be able to choose any Publication, you'll need to make them all live.

Attributes that belong to Publications that are only used implicitly (through the 'Include Child Publications' checkbox) do not need to be made live.

We are aware that some (if not all) customers would prefer it if the attributes were only specific to the *Schema* across all Publications -- and will look into improving this in the future.